# swagger - how to add custom header parameters in request details

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

```
 parameters:
  - in: "body"
    name: "body"
    description: "Pet object that needs to be added to the store"
    required: true
    schema:
      $ref: "#/definitions/Pet"
  - in: "header"
    name: "user"
    description: "username in header paramter"
    required: false
```

Adding above lines of code in POST request of the exaple given in
https://editor.swagger.io/

It gives me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header parameter needs a `type`.

```yaml
  - in: "header"
    name: "user"
    description: "username in header paramter"
    required: false
    type: string    # <-----------
```